# Unpredictable pointer behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, openframeworks

At the moment I am building a cloth physics app using OpenFrameworks. I'm new to C++, for a heads up.

In my app, two 'neighbor' particle objects are passed to a spring object as pointers. As a test, I have the spring object draw lines between the two particles (between their 3d vector positions). For some reason, these lines are different every time I run the program, even though no random values are involved. When I cout the values of the particle positions from the spring struct, they often are ridiculous values like -4.15301e-12. I'm following example code almost verbatim, so I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong.

Here is the example code I'm following:

https://sites.google.com/site/ofauckland/examples/17-cloth-physics

Here is my Spring struct:

```
#pragma once
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "Particle.h"

struct Spring {

    float k, restLength;
    Particle *a, *b;
    ofVec3f posA, posB;

    Spring(Particle *a, Particle *b, float k = .2) : a(a), b(b), k(k) {
        restLength = (b->pos - a->pos).length();
    }

    void update() {
        posA = a->pos;
        posB = b->pos;
    }
    void draw() {
        ofSetLineWidth(5);
        ofSetColor(0, 255, 0);
        ofLine(posA.x, posA.y, posB.x, posB.y);
    }
};
```

The particle struct:

```
#pragma once
#include "ofMain.h"

struct Particle {

    ofVec3f pos;

    Particle(ofVec3f pos) : pos(pos) {
    }

    void update() {
    }
    void draw() {
        ofSetColor(ofRandom(255), 0, 0);
        ofFill();
        ofCircle(pos.x, pos.y, 3); 
    }
};
```

And this is where I pass the two particles to the spring as pointers:

```
#pragma once
#include "ofMain.h" 
#include "Particle.h"
#include "Spring.h"

struct Petal {

    float maxWidth, spacing;
    vector<Particle> particles;
    vector<Spring> springs;

    Petal(float maxWidth, float spacing) : maxWidth(maxWidth), spacing(spacing) {        
        setupPoints();
    }

    void setupPoints() {
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;

        for(int r = 1; r <= maxWidth; r++) {
            x = (int)(r / 2) * -spacing;
            y += spacing;
            for(int c = 1; c <= r; c++) { 
                ofVec3f pos = ofVec3f(x, y, 0);
                Particle p(pos);
                particles.push_back(p); 
                x+=spacing;
            }
        }

        for(int r = maxWidth; r > 0; r--) {
            x = (int)(r / 2) * -spacing;
            y += spacing;
            for(int c = 1; c <= r; c++) { 
                ofVec3f pos = ofVec3f(x, y, 0);  
                Particle p(pos);
                particles.push_back(p); 
                x+=spacing;
            }
        }

        //find neighbors
        for(int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
            Spring s(&particles[i], &particles[findNeighbor(i)]);
            springs.push_back(s);
        }
    }

    int findNeighbor(int pIndex) {
        float leastDist = 0;
        float leastDistIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
            if(i != pIndex) {
                float distance = particles[pIndex].pos.distance(particles[i].pos);
                if(abs(distance) < abs(leastDist) || leastDist == 0) {
                        leastDist = distance;
                        leastDistIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
        return leastDistIndex;

    }

    void update() {   
        for(int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
            particles[i].update();   
        }
        for(int s = 0; s < springs.size(); s++) {
            springs[s].update();
        }
    }
    void draw() {
        for(int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
            particles[i].draw();   
        }
        for(int s = 0; s < springs.size(); s++) {
            springs[s].draw();
        }
    }
};
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD97j.png) is what happens. What's strange is that some of the springs seem to be in the correct position.

Please let me know if I can clarify something.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you making sure that you call `update` before `draw`? In general it is a good idea to ensure that an object is fully constructed (any operation can be called on it) when the constructor completes, but you are doing 2-step initialization: the particles are initialized in the constructor, but the positions, `k` and `restLength` are not.

Comment: I took your advice about initializing the k and restlength in the constructor. And yes, update is called before draw.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `particles` vector holds `Particles` by value, and the `vector` can copy and move these values around. When you pass `Particles` as pointers to the `Spring`, you are passing the address of something that might not be there at some point in the future. I am not sure if this is the problem, but it certainly is something that needs fixing.

Comment: This makes sense, although by the time I create the pointers, I'm done adding elements to the Particles vector. The addresses still change after this?

So should I use an array instead to ensure address stability?

Comment: @Miles you should assume that they could be moved at any time. You could use an array, but could also ask yourself if you really need to pass pointers. You could also hold vectors of smart pointers instead of values. There are many solutions, but I don't really know your use-case exactly.

Comment: I thought of a solution, but it doesn't seem to work.

I passed the pointer of the particles vector, and the indexes of the first and second particles to the spring struct. Would the address of the particle vector itself be subject to change?

Comment: EDIT: Alright, I have a working solution, albeit a bit of a hack. Every frame I pass a reference of the particles vector to the spring struct.

Comment: @Miles the vector's address shouldn't change. I think the question is whether the `Spring` struct really needs pointers, or if it can take the `Particles` by value.